# Split String using Pattern into new line in Postgress

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using below query to get the Output as below. I want to make function so that i will pass that string and get the output as expected output. Each data present in `{` and `}` bracket needs to be display in each row.

String:- `{$..Properties[*]}-{$..Layer_Index}+{$..Name==Value()}/{$..Properties(Name==True)}`

Expected Output:-

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_matches()` for that:

```
select (regexp_matches(input, '\{(\$[^\}]+)\}', 'g'))[1]
```

where `input` is your string you want to parse.

`regexp_matches()` returns multiple matches per row as an array. The `(..)[1]` then picks the first element of that array.

I think this should work with Postgres 9.2 as well.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ba0a2130994b70ae626c8bde0de4be08)